# AngularJs data binding not working with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I feel like I am missing something obvious with some input text in ionic.
I am using `angular-ui-router` with this route:

```
 $stateProvider.state('findPersons', {
   url : '/findPersons',
   templateUrl : 'html/findPersons.html',
   controller : 'findPersonsCtrl'
 });
```

This is the text input code in `findPersons.html`:

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Key Word" ng-model="keyWord">
  </label>
  <button ng-click="findPersons()" class="button button-bar-inline">Load</button>
</div>
```

Then I use the `keyword` to request a rest API this way:

```
bockmoiApp.controller("findPersonsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.results= null;
  $scope.numberOfResults=-1;
  $scope.keyWord="";

  $scope.findPersons = function() {

    $http({
      method : 'GET',
      url : 'http://localhost:8080/bockmoi/rest/findPersons?keyWord='
          +$scope.keyWord+'&page=0&size=2'
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.results = response.data;
      $scope.numberOfResults=$scope.results.numberOfElements;
    },function errorCallback(response) {

    });
  }
});
```

And I am wondering why when I hit the `load` button, the keyWord value is always replaced by `""` before the request is sent, which causes the fetching of all the first `size` results in the remote database! Nevetheless, this code is working on a native html,css and angularjs code without ionic.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to be using "dot notation". Because of inheritance, simple values will not do two way binding.

Comment: Please look into my following answer , I have post the details and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using "dot notation". Because of inheritance, simple values will not do two way binding.

Please use the following code for two way data binding with ionic

**In controller**

```
$scope.test={keyWord : ""};
```

**In view**

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Key Word" ng-model="test.keyWord">
    </label>
    <button ng-click="findPersons()" class="button button-bar-inline">Load</button>
</div>
```

**Live Example** are [here](https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/vgOoba) & same issue are [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scope-controller-data-binding/1734).

Read more details from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Hope this well help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links, i have spend a day on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code everything works fine. 
Possible errors

- URL in the $http call is in two lines. Fix it.

  ```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.results= null;
     $scope.numberOfResults=-1;
     $scope.keyWord="";

     $scope.findPersons = function() {
      var URL= "http://localhost:8080/bockmoi/rest/findPersons?keyWord="+$scope.keyWord+'&page=0&size=2';
      console.log(URL);
      $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/bockmoi/rest/findPersons?keyWord='+$scope.keyWord+'&page=0&size=2'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.results = response.data;
      $scope.numberOfResults=$scope.results.numberOfElements;

      },function errorCallback(response) {

    });
  }
  });
  ```

I tried printing your URL after the button click as in the above code and the behaviour is as expected.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/V784gx8Zv6W5RLsgi0vG)**

Comment: That is not the problem, like i said, i got this working without ionic as you just did,   note that logging keyWord this way $scope.findPersons = function() {
    console.log($scope.keyWord);  ...  shows that the keyWord value is replaced by the initialisation value when i i hit the load button, very weird behaviour

Comment: @PhilippeSimo are you available in team viewer??

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code, but I could not reproduce your problem. Sorry :( . Just a plus, whether you would like to improve you code, you can follow john papa's advices https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to comment yet. Just for my own questions :(