# Can't read $scope in Ionic 1 / angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this piece of HTML:

```
      <div class="item item-icon-left" ion-datetime-picker="" time="" ng-model="timeValue">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-clock positive"></i>
        <p><strong">{{timeValue | date:'HH:mm'}}</strong></p>           
     </div>
```

And in my controller I have this function that will fire when a toggle is activated:

```
    $scope.funCheck = function(check) {     
        console.log($scope.timeValue);          
    };
```

And I use this: https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker to pick a time and set it.

It works fine to pick the time, however, in the function I'm geting undefined and I dont know why.
I want to get the time I picked and do some stuff in my controller with the $Scope.

Comment: use in controller $scope.dateTime = {
timeValue : new Date()
} and in model ng-model="dateTime.timeValue"

Comment: I have posted the answer and documentation link of angular please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using "dot notation". Because of inheritance, simple values will not do two way binding.

Please use the following code for two way data binding with ionic

use in controller

```
$scope.dateTime = { timeValue : '' }
```

and in model `ng-model="dateTime.timeValue"`

Read more details from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533242/angularjs-data-binding-not-working-with-ionic/41534037#41534037).

Hope this well help!

Comment: Actually, I still need your help.Doing console.log($scope.dateTime.timeValue); won't show the time I picked, it will just show up empty.

Comment: Have you add ng-model dateTime.timeValue

Comment: Yeah, ignore me, it's too early in the morning. I've put the $scope.dateTime = { timeValue : '' }  inside the function, and of course it'll set the date to nothing. I moved them out of it and it's done. Thanks.